# Certain Clips are stopped at frame 44100 - Java sound

Tags: java, audio

I have this code for playing the sound from the given sound file:

```
public class SoundPlayer {
    private Clip clip;
    private String sound = "bomb.wav";

    public SoundPlayer() {
        try {
            clip = loadClip();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private Clip loadClip() throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
        AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(sound));
        AudioFormat format = audio.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        final Clip clip =  (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(audio);

        clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {

            @Override
            public void update(LineEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event);
                System.out.println(clip.getFramePosition());
            }
        });

        return clip;
    }

    public void playSound(){
        System.out.println(clip.getFrameLength());
        clip.start();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
        Thread.sleep(2000); //Let open the file
        sp.playSound();
        Thread.sleep(10000); //Wait for the playback to finish
    }

}
```

It plays some sounds without and problems but playback of some sounds (the sounds of exploding bomb) does not work well. For these bomb sounds, the playback always stops at frame 44100 and I don't understand why.

I added debug code to follow the frames which are being played. First number is length in frames, the second is frame when the clip starts and the last is frame positions when it stops.

Output for playing bomb sounds:

```
72846
Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@659bd1ca
44099
Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@659bd1ca
44100
```

I uploaded the explosion sounds here:

http://speedy.sh/v5QTy/bomb.wav

http://speedy.sh/nxysB/explosion.wav

Sound which plays ok:

http://speedy.sh/NzBJr/adios.wav

EDIT: This happens only on Linux - Ubuntu 12.04 with Oracle JDK 1.7.0_51

Is there another easy-to-use sound API which (unlike java.sound) is really without cross-platform issues? This is not my first issue with java.sound under Linux.

Comment: I thought maybe the files were damaged or unusual but I checked them out and they are OK. I'm not a Clip guy though so I don't know the answer.

Comment: Strange that it's exactly 44,100, which probably also is the sampling rate of the audio file... Coincidence?

Comment: perhaps the internal buffers are set up for blocks of 1 second, hence the exact correlation to 44100

Comment: Same here with another sound file - even more strange, sometimes (<5% of all times) it plays correct. Also Ubuntu (17.04)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post via a link from a more recent person having the same issue. I don't have an answer as to why the example code doesn't work. It all looks good to me.

I just wanted to suggest trying the newly coded [AudioCue](http://adonax.com/AudioCue) (BSD type license) as an alternative. It behaves very much like a Clip, but has some advantages. The data is loaded into a float array and output via a SourceDataLine. The implementation is only three classes, two of which are for adding line listening capabilities. As a bonus, it supports concurrent playback, and real time fading for volume, panning and pitch. It only works with stereo 44100 16-bit format ("CD quality") or float arrays loaded directly that follow that format.

I'm very curious if it will work on Ubuntu. Since it plays via a SourceDataLine, it should work across the usual Java platforms.